# GCP created SObject is not immediately available in apex

Tags: apex, callout

I have a lwc component, in that, when clicking a link it will do a rest callout to GCP. GCP side will handle the callout, insert an SObject into salesforce, then return the newly created SObject id in the response of the first callout. Then in Salesforce end, I will query immediately based on the record id.

However, it turns out that I have got 0 result in the query. Is there a delay the transaction which I can query the object?

When GCP returns me with the Id of the SObject, the SObject should have already been created otherwise the Id won't be available. So what might be the cause and how should I fix it?

I don't think apex has a built-in sleep or wait function, and since I need to return the queried result to lwc front-end, I don't think I can use async function in apex. So any suggestions?

Comment: does the running user have viz onto the newly created object? (sharing rules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a small, but non-zero, delay where the record might not yet be available outside of the transaction that created it, since sharing and other calculations are deferred outside of the transaction that created the record. I forget the exact timing, but it's on the order of maybe dozens of milliseconds in most cases. You can wait for the record using `FOR UPDATE`:

```
CalloutResponse res = doCallout(payload);
sObject whatever = [SELECT Id FROM TheObject WHERE Id = :res.recordId FOR UPDATE];
```

You can think of FOR UPDATE as Apex's "sleep" function when waiting for database results, as it will wait for 5-10 seconds without using CPU time (towards the governor time limit) while waiting to acquire the row lock.